# Building Customize Spark

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

We are creating a customize version of Spark since we are changing some lines of code from ALS.scala. We build the customize spark version using
mvn command:

```
./make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn
```

However, upon using the customized version of Spark, we run into this error:

[image]

Do you guys have some idea on what causes the error and how we might solve the issue?

I am actually using a jar file in the local machine by building them using sbt: sbt compile then sbt clean package and putting the jar file here: /Users/user/local/kernel/kernel-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/lib.

However in the hadoop environment, the installation is different. Thus, I use maven to build spark and that's where the error comes in. I am thinking that this error might be dependent on using maven to build spark as there are some reports like this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2075

or probably on building spark assembly files

Comment: Have you run the tests after changing the source code? it seems that there is something ot compatible within the code

Comment: Yes, I tested it on a local machine. It works well. However, it doesn't work in hadoop environment.